# Facebook Analytics: user properties and logged events using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

I have facebook app (Messenger Bot App) where I am logging custom events for each user using the graph API endpoint **/application/activities/**

The events are logged perfectly. What I want to do is creating custom properties for my messenger bot users so I could segment the app data using this properties as described on: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/properties

So what I did was using the graph API endpoint **/application/user_properties/** to create the properties.

It returned "success", the properties were created perfectly and I can see them as possible filters for segmentation on the app analytics page. But this filters always return no results!

I think the problem is: events are logged for specific "fb_user_id" but in user properties endpoint there is nothing to relate "fb_user_id" with the newly created properties.

on FB documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/properties it is stated:

> When you set a user ID, this ID is stored on the user's device and
>   included in app events logged from that device.

This means when calling the event logging endpoint there should be a parameter to hold the user id created by me when setting the user properties. But I am not able of finding this parameter. I tried send it as **custom_events["_app_user_id"]** but results remains the same and on app analytics page I can see the filters but it is useless.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I have the same problem (2 years later). Any help on this?

Comment: Asked the question to Facebook, just in case it helps anybody: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/604760330039139

Answer (score 0):

[Whereas](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/f7531a838a1ec3308721f335e801ac9f508feee4/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.m#L671) `custom_events["_app_user_id"]` is the field for app event payloads, it [looks like](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.m#L530) the field is `custom_events["user_unique_id"]` for user property payloads.