# Facebook bot analytics custom_events events keeps=0

Tags: facebook, events, analytics, custom-events

following the rules I include this as a new question, but this is directly related with these ones, hope this is what expect stackoverflow's administrators:

[Facebook Analytics: user properties and logged events using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829743/facebook-analytics-user-properties-and-logged-events-using-graph-api)

[Facebook bot analytics event logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277454/facebook-bot-analytics-event-logging)

I send custom_events requests to FB.Analytics, but the event associated counters keeps always zero as you can see in the attached file,
not matter how many times I send the request with a success return, the counters keeps=0.
I didn't know if the problem could be related with facebookID,
now I've tried including it, but the problem keeps anyway.

'custom_events=[{"user_unique_id": 1000xxxxx682, ...

BTW,I send the request from my Linux Ubuntu.

Please did you find any way of solving this?, Any idea of the source of this problem?
thanks a lot,
regards.

--------- Request:

> curl -F 'event=CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS' \
>               -F 'advertiser_tracking_enabled=1' \
>               -F 'application_tracking_enabled=1' \
>               -F 'custom_events=[{"_eventName": "fb_onboarding_OK", "n_contents_showed": 10, "_logTime": 1499965797}]' \
>               https://graph.facebook.com/12XXXXXXXX27YYY36/activities

{"success":true}

>
[image]

Comment: The only difference I have is that I have set `advertiser_tracking_enabled` and `application_tracking_enabled` both set to 0. Eventually my custom event names showed up in the events area - with zero counts, but do not display in event debugging. Oh yes, and `_valueToSum` set to `1` as part of the actual custom event.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it is just a waiting game. Data is starting to populate now, a few hours after starting to send the custom events. The custom events are now starting to show in the event debugging area too  - again it seems hours later - not "within 30 seconds" or so.